# Getting source code of other domain website using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cross-domain

I would like to get part of the youtube page source code.

I tried cross domain ajax technique such as yahoo yql , JsonP. With the help of the yahoo YQL , I can grab part of the source code. However, since it may be the different domain, what I get from the ajax response text do not have the parameter in it. How to fix the problem without using server side program ? Thanks

Link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6JiCJ5x3Qw

You can see from element inspector , there is an line `<div id="player-api" class="player-width player-height off-screen-target watch-content player-api" style="overflow: hidden;">`

And I would like to get all the element within this div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proxy script at your own server, if you have no control over the endpoint (youtube in this case)

So instead of calling a youtube url you will call yourproxyscript?some_arguments. Now the "yourproxyscript" will load youtube url and return it to your ajax call, bypassing any cross-domain issues.

Comment: i have tried using YQL but the youtube seems only include the video content only when directly access it

Comment: If you look at the source of the url you gave (the actual unmodified html source, returned by a raw request), you'll notice that your required div is empty. I think it is filled in later by javascript. That makes things complicated. Assuming you want to display a video in your page, why not just use youtube's embed code?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the simplest thing to do may be to use the YouTube API.

However, in general, what you'd want to do is load the page into an iFrame rather than a div:

`<iframe id="iframe" src="http://targetwebsite.com/"></iframe>`

And then get the HTML of the iFrame as follows:

`document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for you help . I tried this approach but it show "Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6JiCJ5x3Qw' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Comment: Ah the sameorigin policy. In this case, you might be better off using the YouTube API.